Prove the following result on continuity.
Continuity of Eigenvalues
Let $A\in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ and $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ with algebraic multiplicity $m$. Then ($\forall \epsilon>0$)($\exists \delta >0$)($\forall E\in\mathbb C^{n,n}, ||E||<\delta)( \mathbb B_{\epsilon}(\lambda)=\{\xi\in \mathbb C| |\xi-\lambda|<\epsilon\}$ contains $m$ eigenvalues of $A+E$ with calculated multiplicity.
)
My attempt:-
Let $\epsilon$ be a given positive real number. I feel this result has to deal with continuity of eigenvalue. We need to define a continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb C^{n,n}$ to $\mathbb C.$ But I don't know how to define continuous function explicitly. Could you help me? Also I don't understand this statement $\mathbb B_{\epsilon}(\lambda)=\{\xi\in \mathbb C| |\xi-\lambda|<\epsilon\}$ contains $m$ eigenvalues of $A+E$ with calculated multiplicity. What do you mean by the set contains $m$ eigenvalues of $A+E$ with calculated multiplicity?

It really just boils down to roots of the characteristic polynomial $f(t, E) = \det(tI - (A + E))$. When $E = 0$, it has $m$ repeated roots at $t = \lambda$. By continuity, if $|E|$ is small, $f(t, E)$ should have $m$ roots near $\lambda$ (i.e., in $\mathbb{B}_\epsilon(\lambda)$). See if you can turn this into a rigorous argument.

If you have studied complex analysis you should state which texts you've used and what results you know.  A lot of popular texts do a terrible job with the Argument Principle though; I of course second the recommendation of Beardon's book.  If you have not studied complex analysis you probably shouldn't be asking this question though if you know enough techniques from real analysis and basic topology I vaguely recall a workaround in Horn's Matrix Analysis using Schur Triangulation and sequences, as a contradiction argument.


“We need to define a continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb C^{n,n}$ to $\mathbb C$”. No. You are confusing topological continuity of eigenvalues with functional continuity. Unless $n=1$, the $f$ you seek may not exist. E.g. the two eigenvalues of
$$
A(z)=\pmatrix{0&z\\ 1&0}
$$
are the two square roots of $A$. If there exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb C^{2\times2}\to C$ that takes every matrix $M$ to one of its eigenvalues, then $f\circ A:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ will be a continuous function that takes every complex number $z$ to a square root of $z$. Yet it is well-known that such a function does not exist.
By topological continuity, we mean more or less the epsilon-delta statement at the beginning of your question, but as it stands, the statement in your question is not quite right. What does “$m$ eigenvalues of $A+E$” mean? At least $m$ eigenvalues or exactly $m$ eigenvalues? On one hand, if it means at least $m$ eigenvalues, then the statement is technically correct but not what we want — we do want the open disc to contain exactly $m$ eigenvalues, so that when the radius of the disc shrinks to zero, those $m$ eigenvalues converge to the $m$ copies of $\lambda$. On the other hand, if the phrase means exactly $m$ eigenvalues, then the statement is wrong. For a counterexample, consider the case where $n>m=1$, $\epsilon=2\rho(A)$ and $E=0$. In this case, the open disc $|\xi-\lambda|<\epsilon$ contains not only $m$, but all $n$ eigenvalues of $A+E$.
The statement in your question can be corrected by replacing “$\forall\epsilon>0$” by either “for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$” or “$\forall\epsilon\in(0,r)$”, where $r>0$ is any fixed real number such that $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ in the open disc $|z-\lambda|<r$.
A nice proof of topological continuity of the zeroes of polynomials can be found on pp. 109-110 in chapter 8 of the book Complex Analysis: the Argument Principle in Analysis and Topology written by Alan Beardon. The proof only makes use of properties of winding number. The full statement of Rouche’s theorem or the argument principle are not needed. Let $\lambda$ be a zero of $p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k$ with multiplicity $m$. Let $r>0$ be a sufficiently small number such that the only zeroes of $p$ inside the circle $|z-\lambda|<r$ are the $m$ copies of $\lambda$. For any $\epsilon\in(0,r)$, define $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb C$ by $\gamma(t)=\lambda+\epsilon e^{it}$. Denote the image of $\gamma$ (i.e., the circle $|z-\lambda|=\epsilon$) by $[\gamma]$. Then
$$
l:=\inf_{z\in[\gamma]}|p(z)|>0.
$$
Let $q(z)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kz^k$ be another polynomial. On the circle $[\gamma]$ we have
$$
|p(z)-q(z)|
\le\max_{0\le k\le n}|a_k-b_k|\sum_{k=0}^n\epsilon^k.
$$
Therefore, when $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small and the coefficients of $q$ are such that $|a_k-b_k|<\delta$ for all $k$, we will have $|p(z)-q(z)|<l\le|p(z)|$ on $[\gamma]$. So, by the dog-walking lemma, the winding numbers $W(p\circ\gamma,0)$ and $W(q\circ\gamma,0)$ are the same. That is, $p$ and $q$ have the same number of zeroes inside the circle $[\gamma]$. Yet, the only zeroes of $p$ inside $[\gamma]$ are the $m$ copies of $\lambda$. Therefore
$$
\{\xi\in\mathbb C:|\xi-\lambda|<\epsilon,\,q(\xi)=0\}
$$
has cardinality $m$. Now you may apply this result to the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

